# Simple Structure For Each always resulting error The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time

Tags: swiftui

I don't know what is wrong in my code, i already make it as simple as i can and yet it still resulting the same error.

i just add some line with the exact code i already build before without any error, but for some reason error error The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time is always happen.

Below here is my code:

```
struct listData: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()

    let ItemCode: String
    let ItemName: String
    let BrandName: String
    let Quantity: Int
    let Discount: String
    let LineTotal: String
    let Price: String
}

@State private var arrayListDatax = [listData]()
public var body: some View {
     
    ForEach(arrayListDatax) { rd in
                                        
        HStack() {
             
            VStack {
                
                 
                Text("\(rd.BrandName)")
                    .font(.system(size: 13))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,   alignment: .leading)
                
                Text("\(rd.ItemCode)")
                    .bold()
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,   alignment: .leading)
                
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Qty. ")
                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                            .italic()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,   alignment: .leading)
                    
                     
                        Text("\(rd.Quantity)")
                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                            .italic()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,   alignment: .leading)
                    }// HStack
                    
                    HStack {
                       
                        Text("Price. ")
                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                            .italic()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,   alignment: .leading)
                    
                        Text("\(rd.Price)")
                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                            .italic()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,   alignment: .leading)
                        
                    }// HStack

                    HStack {
                       
                    Text("Total. ")
                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                            .italic()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,   alignment: .leading)
                    
                        Text("\(rd.LineTotal)")
                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                            .italic()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,   alignment: .leading)
                        
                    }// HStack


                    
                    /***  ALWAYS RESULT ERROR WHEN I ADD THIS LINE FROM HERE ***/
                    HStack {
                       
                        Text("Price. ")
                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                            .italic()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,   alignment: .leading)
                    
                        Text("\(rd.Price)")
                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                            .italic()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,   alignment: .leading)
                        
                    }// HStack
                    /***** TO HERE ****/
                    
                }//VStack
                
            }//VStack
            .frame(width: 120)
             
            VStack  {
                Text("\(rd.ItemName)")
                    .bold()
                    .font(.system(size: 13))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,   alignment: .leading)
                
                Text("\(rd.ItemName)")
                    .bold()
                    .font(.system(size: 13))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,   alignment: .leading)
            }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity,   alignment: .leading)
            
          
             
        }.padding(.vertical,5)
        //HStack
        
    }//for each
 
}// body
```

thats the code and its not even HALF of what i want to design yet, i don't know how to make it more simpler than i already have.

Comment: Your snapshot is compiled fine with Xcode 11.4. Try to break your body to several subviews. At least extract ForEach cell subview.

Comment: @Asperi sorry sir, i miss some HStack, it will result an error when i add another HStack. but i want to add much more HStack after that too. I already edit the code in my question too.